How to transfer POS USDT in smart contract?
With bsc20 USDT (0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955), i can use
usd = IERC20(usdContract);
and usd.transfer(address,amount);
But in polygon (0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f) i don't know how to call transfer funtion in my smart contract.
Can anyone help show me how? Thanks!
